# Syntax error on multiple-table deletion

Tags: mysql, sql

When I run this:

```
DELETE FROM folders AS fo
LEFT OUTER JOIN files AS fi 
ON fo.folderId = fi.folderId
WHERE fi.folderId IS NULL AND (fo.folderId IN (63,1000))
```

... I get a syntax error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'AS fo LEFT OUTER JOIN files AS fi ON fo.folderId = fi.folderId
>   WHERE fi.fold' at line 1

The code is based in a `SELECT` query that returns the intended rows. What's the reason for the error message?

Comment: What does not work? Do you get an error?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS fo LEFT OUTER JOIN files AS fi ON fo.folderId = fi.folderId WHERE fi.fold' at line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't a surprise that it "doesn't work". When I run your code I get a syntax error:

> SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'AS fo LEFT OUTER JOIN files AS fi  ON fo.folderId
>   = fi.folderId WHERE fi.fold' at line 1

The [correct syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/delete.html) is:

```
DELETE fo -- Note I've added table name
FROM folders AS fo
LEFT OUTER JOIN files AS fi 
ON fo.folderId = fi.folderId
WHERE fi.folderId IS NULL AND (fo.folderId IN (63,1000));
```

Comment: @jon I see you posted the relevant info later. I've edited the question to make it look as it should have been from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE
  FROM folders fo
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                     FROM files fi
                    WHERE fi.folderId = fo.folderId)
   AND fo.folderId IN (63, 1000)
```

Comment: Thanks Rachcha but the JOIN is needed so that I only delete folders that are not in the files table.

Comment: Just a min then, I'll edit my answer and give you an appropriate query for the job.

Comment: Thanks for your help Rachcha but alvaro has got thee answer..I plus oned your answer as it works, but wasn't actuauly the answer to my question... thanks again j